# Setting Values Of Inherited Properties

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x, inheritance

I want to be able to create a concrete instance of a class that inherits from another concrete class, which in turn inherits from an abstract class.

The basic pattern is:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractproperty

class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractproperty
    def x(self):
        pass

    @abstractproperty
    def y(self):
        pass

class Bar(Foo):
    x = None
    y = None

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self.x = value

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self.y

    @y.setter
    def y(self, value):
        self.y = value

class Baz(Bar):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(x=2, y=6)


a = Baz()
```

When I try to create the instance of `Baz` I get a `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` error. (As well as a pylint warning telling me that the signatures of the setter methods don't match the signatures of the base class)

However, if I remove the setters, I get an error `self.x = x AttributeError: can't set attribute`

What's the correct pattern to do this?

Comment: What did you expect from a setter for `x` that sets `x` calling the setter for `x` that sets `x` calling the setter for... This isn't related to the inheritance, that wouldn't work in a standalone class.

Comment: Something very similar to this. I don't understand how to make `x` settable, without having a setter for `x`.

Comment: You need to have another attribute that holds the underlying value (or, given that the getter and setter don't do anything, just stop using a property - this isn't Java!)

Comment: Thanks. The more I use getter and setter decorators, the more I think they're not a good solution for most things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change names for your x() / y() methods or for your x / y properties, for example rename

```
class Bar(Foo):
    x = None
    y = None
```

To:

```
class Bar(Foo):
    x_val = None
    y_val = None
```

And rename the references to x / y as well.

Answer (score 1):

What you did is basically:

```
def x():
    return x()
```

It happened because your `def x` overridden the `x = None`, so x is a function(property) that is calling itself. Avoid this by using another attribute(named differently) for storing the actual value of x.

Example from python docs (https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#property):

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value
```

Note: attribute names starting with underscore should be considered "private" and should not be directly accessed outside of the class. But it's only a convention for programmers, technically they are just normal attributes and you can do whatever you want, but it's nice to follow some convention, isn't it?